# How to insert math symbols as text in Latex without getting error messages

Tags: code

How can I insert `[1+(-1)^n/n, {n, 10}]` (text as it is) in latex without getting any error messages like missing `$` (latex interprets this as an equation), or missing `\` , for the brackets {

I have tried `\text{[1+(-1)^n/n, {n, 10}]}` which still gives the error messages, and I have also tried the verbatim environment and lstlisting environment.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This is a math expression, so the only way I can interpret your request to enter this as text is to assume that you want it to sppear verbatim.  If that is what you mean, then use `\verb9[1+(-1)^n/n, {n, 10}]9` where `9` is used as the "wrapper", i.e., a matching pair of characters that don't appear within the verbatim expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `verbatim` environment or the `\verb|...|` command, depending on the output you want. 
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
In a special environment:
\begin{verbatim}
[1+(-1)^n/n, {n, 10}]
\end{verbatim}
In line: \verb|[1+(-1)^n/n, {n, 10}]|.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possibile alternative using `\mathttt` and `\texttt` commands instead of the correct package called `verbatim`. You can see my code and the output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item First example text in math-mode $\mathtt{[1+(-1)\char`\^n/n,\{n, 10\}]}$
    \item Second example text in text-mode \texttt{[1+(-1)$\char`\^{\texttt{n}}$/n, $\mkern-10mu{\texttt{\textbraceleft}}\texttt{n,10}\texttt{\textbraceright}$]}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```